# How is solid titanium(II) oxide an electrical conductor?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals, solid-state-chemistry, conductivity

Most salts in the solid state are electrical insulators, since the ions are not mobile (e.g. sodium chloride). However, solid titanium(II) oxide, $\ce{TiO (s)}$, is a conductor. How is this so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The electron configuration of $\ce{Ti^{2+}}$ is $\mathrm{[Ar]~3d^2~4s^0}$.

$\ce{TiO}$, like e.g. $\ce{FeO}$, $\ce{CoO}$ and $\ce{NiO}$, adopts the rock salt ($\ce{NaCl}$) structure.

Due to the lower nuclear charge of $\ce{Ti}$ its 3d orbitals are less contracted than that of $\ce{Fe}$, $\ce{Co}$ and $\ce{Ni}$ which allows for overlapping of the 3d orbitals and the formation of a metal d band in $\ce{TiO}$. The d electrons of $\ce{Ti^{2+}}$ partially fill this band and lead to electrical conductivity. $\ce{FeO}$, $\ce{CoO}$ and $\ce{NiO}$ on the other hand are electrical insulators.

Note that in this case it is electrons that act as the mobile charge carriers, not the ions.

Comment: I always thought it was related to defect structures.  $\ce{FeO}$ is a fairly good conductor on that account IIRC.

Comment: As far as I know conductivity of TiO is not related to defect structures. However, $\ce{FeO_{1-x}}$ might not be the best example for an insulator since it rather has the conductivity of a semiconductor than an insulator at normal temperature. Its conductivity is indeed due to $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ holes hopping between Fe sites in the lattice.

Comment: $\ce{Fe_{1-x}O}$ maybe? Much of my job involves dealing with oxide scales, hence I see the q through wustite-colored glasses.

Comment: TiO has a defect NaCl structure (1/6 lattice points are vacant); I've read that this permits a more contracted structure and hence better overlap between 3d orbitals on neighbouring Ti. Disclaimer, I have only very superficial knowledge of solid state chem.