# Why is ruthenium dioxide a conductor while titanium dioxide is an insulator?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, solid-state-chemistry, conductivity, ceramics

Ruthenium dioxide has the same crystal structure as rutile (titanium dioxide), and the metal atoms are in the same oxidation state.  Yet ruthenium dioxide is a metal-like conductor (its resistivity is given by Miao et al. [[1](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tsf.2004.10.032)] as $\pu{40 \mu\Omega{} cm}$ for thin films), while [titanium dioxide is an insulator](http://www.goodfellow.com/E/Titanium-Dioxide.html) with a resistivity of at least $\pu{E13 \Omega{} cm}$ and a band gap of over $\pu{3 eV}.$

Why are the electrical properties of these two ceramics so different?

#### Reference

1. Miao, G. X.; Gupta, A.; Xiao, G.; Anguelouch, A. Epitaxial Growth of Ruthenium Dioxide Films by Chemical Vapor Deposition and Its Comparison with Similarly Grown Chromium Dioxide Films. *Thin Solid Films* **2005**, 478 (1), 159–163. DOI: [10.1016/j.tsf.2004.10.032](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tsf.2004.10.032).

Comment: Well, Ru has more valence electrons.

Comment: More precisely *unpaired* electrons.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/81724/how-is-solid-titaniumii-oxide-an-electrical-conductor

Comment: Note also that there are a number of factors affecting conductivity in metal oxides such as temperature, doping (impurities), and geometry (e.g. thin layers or needles vs. bulk). See http://collaborations.fz-juelich.de/ikp/cgswhp/cgswhp12/program/files_batumi/14-08-2012/Parallel_Session_5/1_Kazimierz.Conder_Batumi.pdf for a nice summary!

Comment: Diamond is a wide band gap insulator/semiconductor (depends on your point of view). Silicon is a good semiconductor, Germanium is ok with a lower band gap. Then alpha-Tin is a semi-metal. Just shows that chemistry does not uniquely translate to solid state band structure.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1369800112000066 shows the band structure. https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/pssa.2210690165, while older, has useful information. Bottom line - like crystal structures do not imply like electronic structure (see also C, Si, Ge, Sn above).